# Does the length of a NSString (or String) impact the performance of isEqualToString: (or ==)?

Tags: objective-c, string, performance, swift

Does the length of the `NSString` (or `String` for Swift) impact the performance of `isEqualToString:` (or `==` for Swift) when the strings are not the same `ID`?

I'll be doing a lot of long string comparisons contained in arrays and am wondering if it would improve performance to store a shorter hash of the strings for the sake of comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no. As long as the strings are *different* lengths, there's no need to compare their contents (because `-isEqualToString:` can do `if (self.length != other.length) return NO;`), so length has no impact on performance.

If the strings are the same length, comparison time increases with the length.

Comment: For the curious, the source code for CFString is here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.17/CFString.c (look for CFStringEqual). I was slightly surprised that the hash isn't used. I guess the chances of it actually helping are pretty small?

Comment: CFString doesn't cache its hash value, so that would likely be as expensive (or more expensive) than doing the comparison.

Comment: The open source code is so awesome to see!  I had no idea that was available. So cool to see how it's implemented.

Comment: Not everything is open source (in particular, just about none of the Objective-C bits are), but enough is that you can see quite a bit of what's going on. It's pretty neat :)